# What are the risks of connecting to database directly from Electron app?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, electron

I'm fairly new at building Electron apps and I've seen a lot of examples where Electron app connects directly to a remote database (MySQL in my case) so I started wondering what the problems might be with doing it that way. My first thought was to have a remote API (built on top of Express) which would communicate with the database and Electron app (React) would just utilize that API.

Any advice? Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: there is no "best practice", just ask your self, why the extra step with a HTTP API ?
Did you expect that other services call your api or only the electron app ?

Comment: Depends on your case. If you intend to reuse the code in non-Electron app then this is likely not a good idea.

Comment: If your database is publicly hosted on the internet, and any random user can download the app to connect to your database, all the data is essentially public and everyone has unlimited write access for all intents and purposes. Maybe not so ideal. If it’s a non-public app… well, it depends.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  I modified the subject title and edited the question slightly and do not think this primarily calls for opinion any more.  I also think it was entirely possible to answer with facts before (as I did).  I hope others vote to reopen.

Comment: You should never be sending SQL through the internet, IMO. Especially if it's being run on anything besides your own servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem with directly connecting to the database is you have to embed the database credentials in the electron app which makes them available to anyone who wants to snoop through the code.  In addition, once the credentials are exposed, you lose control over what anyone can do to your database.

This is why you would usually give the user their own credentials, have the user authenticate to a web server and then have the web server be the only one who can directly talk to the remote database.  You can then completely control what happens to the database since your web server is the intermediary and the only one that actually talks to the database.

This doesn't mean that there aren't some circumstances where you might want the client to talk directly to the database as it really depends upon what you're doing, what the data is and what the risk exposure is for allowing untrusted code to directly manipulate the data in the database.

Remember, you cannot protect credentials embedded in a client.  They can be discovered by the client and used for other things.

Comment: That's a good point, but most DBs including MySQL have their own access management. I'd worry more about the necessity to expose DB server to external connections if this could be avoided. Of course, additional abstraction layer makes it more future proof.

Comment: Thank you for you answer however could you give an example of the app where client has to talk directly to the database? The app I am working on is for managing workers, workloads and work hours of a small local business. @jfriend00

Comment: @scarably - I can't think of one I'd provide direct access to the database over the wide open internet as it seems like there are just too many opportunities for abuse.  Perhaps on a local network where there's more limited access or where you have some other level of sufficient access control (like a VPN with it's own login).